# How to modify InstallShield script(s) to install Win XP 32-bit app on Win 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, installshield

I have a relatively large (~ 17 components) application that has been running on Win XP 32-bit.  I need to modify the InstallShield install script(s) to allow it to be installed on Win 7 32-bit and/or 64-bit. Because of the size and number of install scripts, I don't want to regenerate them, just make the minimum manual modifications to permit the Win 7 installs.

Running the current (Win XP) installer gets the following message from Setup.exe:
"The version of this file is not comparible with the version of Windows you're running..."

What is needed to get Setup created that will run on Win 7 32-bit, 64-bit and XP 32-bit?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of InstallShield are you running?  It's sounds like it might be an old 16 bit version.  You may have to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I think this question has a fundamental problem: We don't know if the 32bit program (the one that gets installed) was written with 64bit in mind.

Comment: The original InstallShield was version "11".  I have upgraded to "2011" for Win 7 support.

Comment: The 32-bit program was not designed for 64-bit so it will have to be installed as a 32-bit application.